# Maven: exclude dependency from shade plugin

Tags: java, maven, packaging

I've seen next string after `mvn clean install`

> Including com.sun.jersey.contribs:jersey-multipart:jar:1.5 in the
>   shaded jar

**Problem:** I can't make it not shaded even I've added exlusion for maven-shade-plugin (see code below)

**My maven-shade-plugin:**

```xml
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <filters>
                            <filter>
                                <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                            </filter>
                        </filters>
                        <artifactSet>
                            <excludes>
//Here ==>                      <exclude>com.sun.jersey.contribs:jersey-multipart:jar</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                        </artifactSet>
                        <transformers>
                            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                <manifestEntries>
                                    <Main-Class>Main</Main-Class>
                                    <Build-Number>123</Build-Number>
                                </manifestEntries>
                            </transformer>
                            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                <resource>META-INF/spring.handlers</resource>
                            </transformer>
                            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                <resource>META-INF/spring.schemas</resource>
                            </transformer>
                        </transformers>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

According to http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/shade-mojo.html, your exclusion syntax is wrong:

> Artifacts to include/exclude from the final artifact. Artifacts are denoted by composite identifiers of the general form **groupId:artifactId:type:classifier**. ... For convenience, the syntax *groupId* is equivalent to *groupId:*:*:**, *groupId:artifactId* is equivalent to *groupId:artifactId:*:** and ***groupId:artifactId:classifier* is equivalent to *groupId:artifactId:*:classifier***.

So either use `com.sun.jersey.contribs:jersey-multipart:*:jar` or `com.sun.jersey.contribs:jersey-multipart` for your exclusion.

```
               <artifactSet>
                  <excludes>
                     <exclude>com.sun.jersey.contribs:jersey-multipart</exclude>
                   </excludes>
               </artifactSet>
```

Comment: `<exclude>org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs:*:jar</exclude>` is still Including org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs:jar:3.0.0 in the shaded jar.I have also tried  `org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs `..but its not working

Answer (score 9):

Add scope tag in dependency tag with value as 'provided'. It will exclude that dependency.
[image: Similar to below dependency]

Comment: This is working fine, only if you don't need those dependencies for local work (e.g. testing purposes) before building the distributable package.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone, who made a lot of steps to exclude some *transitive* artifact from your fat jar and it still presented, there may be two causes:

1. This dependency is **transitive for other dependency**, not that one, where you've made exclusion. Thus you need to add exclusion tag somewhere else (if your exclusion is located in `<dependencies>` section, not plugin-level).

`mvn dependency:tree` is very useful for these searches.

2. These dependency classes comes to your jar straight from some dependency artifact **as ordinary classes, not transitive dependency**.

There is some chance that one of dependencies of your project represents fat jar. Certain classes which you want to exclude comes to your project as ordinary classes, not transitive dependency. Thus Maven unable to exclude it. Also this is a reason that Maven’s provided scope is not working (classes still presented in your jar).

More details here: https://mchesnavsky.tech/maven-dependency-exclusion-not-working/